# Wasserstein Distance with Translations

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, metric-spaces, optimal-transport

I am studying [this book](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.00567) about Optimal Transport, and in Remark 2.19 it talks about translation in Variance, where it is stated that a nice property of Wasserstein Distances is the ability to factor out translations: 
    $$\mathcal{W}_2 (T_{\tau\#}\alpha \; , \; T_{\tau'\#}\beta)^2= \mathcal{W}_2(\alpha,\beta)^2-
 2\langle \tau -\tau' \; , \; \mathbf{m}_\alpha - \mathbf{m}_\beta \rangle + \|\tau -\tau'\|^2$$
where $\mathbf{m}_\alpha \triangleq \int_\mathcal{X}xd\alpha(x) \in \mathbb{R}^d$ is the mean of a measure $\alpha$.

The proceeded to write that:
$$ \mathcal{W}_2(\alpha,\beta)^2=\mathcal{W}_2(\bar{\alpha},\bar{\beta})^2+\|\mathbf{m}_\alpha - \mathbf{m}_\beta \|^2$$

Where $\mathcal{W}_2(\bar{\alpha},\bar{\beta})^2=\mathcal{W}_2 (T_{\tau\#}\alpha \; , \; T_{\tau'\#}\beta)^2$.

Now, I can't wrap my head around how the term $\|\mathbf{m}_\alpha - \mathbf{m}_\beta \|^2$ came to be in the equation. I've tried to trace backwards, but I got stuck. Here is my attempt:
\begin{align}
  2 \langle \tau-\tau',\mathbf{m}_\alpha-\mathbf{m}_\beta\rangle  - \|\tau -\tau'\|^2 &= \|\mathbf{m}_\alpha-\mathbf{m}_\beta\|^2 \\
  2 \langle \tau-\tau',\mathbf{m}_\alpha-\mathbf{m}_\beta\rangle  &= \|\tau -\tau'\|^2 + \|\mathbf{m}_\alpha-\mathbf{m}_\beta\|^2 \\
    \langle \tau-\tau',\mathbf{m}_\alpha-\mathbf{m}_\beta\rangle &= \frac{\|\tau -\tau'\|^2 + \|\mathbf{m}_\alpha-\mathbf{m}_\beta\|^2}{2}
\end{align}

I haven't studied analysis or measure theory, but I am trying to understand as much as I could. I thought that this is an inner product and that $\tau-\tau'$ is the difference between translations, which could be viewed as some vector, and similarly for the difference between the means of the discrete measures which I assume that they yield the center of the discrete measures $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

I am pretty sure something is wrong in my understanding, or at least my basics. So, my questions are:

- where did I go wrong?
- is that an inner product?
- what is the definition of this $\langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle$ notation?
- and what is the definition of these norms $\|\cdot\|^2$ in the context of
  the Wasserstein distances?

Thanks

EDIT: I am using $\triangleq$ as the equal with a "def" on top.

EDIT: The purpose is self-study. I am not enrolled anywhere so it isn't a homework.

EDIT: From Remark 2.19 in the book: $(\bar{\alpha},\bar{\beta})$ are the "centered" zero mean measures $\bar{\alpha}=T_{\mathbf{m}_\alpha \#} \alpha$

Comment: The equation $W_2(\alpha,\beta)^2=W_2(\bar\alpha,\bar\beta)^2+\lVert M_\alpha-m_\beta\rVert^2$ only holds for $\tau=m_\alpha$, $\tau'=m_\beta$. This should solve your problems. In this context, $\lVert\cdot\rVert$ and $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ simply denote the usual Euclidean norm and inner product.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.

Hmm.. So it only holds for when the translations are equal to the mean? The remark in the book (Remark 2.19) claims that one of the features of the Wasserstein distance is that it is translation invariant. So, what is it that I misunderstand here?

Update: I've added a point I haven't mentioned about what $(\bar{\alpha},\bar{\beta})$ are.

Comment: Translation invariance follows from the special case $\tau=\tau'$. And if you insert the definition of $\bar \alpha$, $\bar\beta$ into the first equation, you get the second one.

Answer (score 1):

Let ${\tau}=m_a,\tau'=m_b$, since 
$2\langle \mathbf{m}_\alpha - \mathbf{m}_\beta \; , \; \mathbf{m}_\alpha - \mathbf{m}_\beta \rangle = 2\|\mathbf{m}_\alpha -\mathbf{m}_\beta'\|^2$,
you get from the first equation that 
$\mathcal{W}_2 (T_{m_\alpha \#}\alpha \; , \; T_{m_\beta \#}\beta)^2= \mathcal{W}_2(\alpha,\beta)^2-
 2\langle \mathbf{m}_\alpha - \mathbf{m}_\beta \; , \; \mathbf{m}_\alpha - \mathbf{m}_\beta \rangle + \|\mathbf{m}_\alpha -\mathbf{m}_\beta\|^2 $ 
$= \mathcal{W}_2(\alpha,\beta)^2- \|\mathbf{m}_\alpha -\mathbf{m}_\beta\|^2
$ . 
Rearrange the items, you get the results that you want.